# (Python Newbie) Following e-book "A Byte of Python" - Issue with first program

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hoping some one can help me out with an issue I have with my first program from the e-book "A byte of Python".

The e-book is based on Python 2.7.

Program: zip a source directory and format it with a particular "Name" and place it in the destination directory.

The E-Books code to do this task is:

```
import os
import time

# source directory of files to backup
source = ["/root/Documents/test"]

# target location for files to be backed up to
target_dir = "/root/Documents/Backup"

target = target_dir + os.sep

time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M") + ".zip"

# if target path does not exist, create it
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir)

# Command to zip files
zip_command = "zip -r {0}".format(target).join(source)

#run the backup
print "Zip command is:"
print (zip_command)
print "Running"

# Check to see if backup was successful

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
print "Successfull backup to", target

else:

print "Backup Failed"
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Zip command is:
/root/Documents/test
Running
Backup Failed
sh: 1: /root/Documents/test: Permission denied

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have checked the permissions on the folders, attempted to run the code as super user etc.. but I am having no luck, I am extremely new to Python and don't really want to continue on with this e-book until I have found a resolution to this problem as it re-uses and refines this code as I go on.

I have a feeling the problem could be related to the zip_command?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are constructing the command wrongly!

```
zip_command = "zip -r {0}".format(target)   +  " "   + " ".join(source)
    #  Result: zip -r /root/Documents/Backup <space>   /root/Documents/test
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I actually typed that part of the code incorrectly. 

I have changed it exactly how it is in the e-book, I was tampering around with it a bit.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, so simple argh!! thanks for your prompt response.